# Looking for alerts or notifications in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Watch the next image.

[image]

It's something like an alert or notification and some of them have a close button to the right of the border.

I would like to implement that in my `MVC 4` project where the alert can closed (I guess this is done using COOKIES)

I don't know if this can be done using `JQUERY` o some `HtmlHelper` extension. Can you mention me name components which I can use? I really don't know any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

approach 1:
you can make a partial view, and hide it when they click on the x in a corner

you would show the partial view selectively based on a value int he viewmodel

```
in the container viewmodel you could have...
@{if (Model.IsVisitor)
       @Html.Partial("CustomAlert",Model.Message);
 }};
```

and then you could have a parital view CustomAlert.cshtml

```
<div id="custom-alert" class="custom-alert">
   <div id="close-custom-alert" class="custom-alert-top-right">&#x2716;</div>
   <p style="width:95%"> @Model </p>
</div>

<script>
       $('#close-custom-alert').click(function(){$('#custom-alert').hide()});
</script>

<style>
   .custom-alert { position: relative; background-color:cornsilk; }
   .custom-alert-top-right   { position : absolute; top:5px; right:5px; padding-5px; }
</style>
```

---

approach 2
see jquery ui modal dialog  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default and http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal. You can pop the dialog based on a value in the view like

```
$(function(){
 if ('@Model.IsVisitor'){
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
   height: 140,
   modal: true
  });
 }
});
```